# Rails messed up cant' find gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know what's going on with my installation of ruby / rails under OSX Mountain Lion.

I start with a black rails application, run bundle and listing the installed bundles with `bundle show` I get this:

```
[..]
* sqlite3 (1.3.7)
* thor (0.17.0)
* tilt (1.3.3)
* treetop (1.4.12)
[..]
```

As soon as I run rake db:migrate I get the following error:

```
Could not find thor-0.17.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But, as shown, thor-0.17 is installed. If I force it:

```
sudo gem install --version 0.17 thor 
Successfully installed thor-0.17.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for thor-0.17.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for thor-0.17.0...
```

And run the migration again, I keep having dependency errors (in this case "Could not find formtastic-2.2.1 in any of the sources") for gems that bundle says are already installed. Any help? Thanks

**EDIT**

- Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/WSz5dLrm
- Gemfile.lock: http://pastebin.com/2kuFz1kK

Comment: Hey, can you please paste your whole Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in a gist / pastebin ?

Comment: What happens if you run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: this gives an error installing sqlite3


/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

Comment: can u post o/p of the following commands, ruby -v and if you are using rvm then rvm rubies, there seems to be a ruby mismatch between the default ruby which comes with mac and ruby installed later.

Answer (score 0):

So after using your Gemfile I got the following error :

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       rails (= 3.2.8) ruby depends on
>         railties (= 3.2.8) ruby
>
> ```
> sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) ruby depends on
>   railties (3.2.11)
> ```
>
> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":   In
>   snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>       actionpack (3.2.11)
>
> In Gemfile:
>       meta_search (>= 1.1.0.pre) ruby depends on
>         actionpack (~> 3.1.0.alpha) ruby
>
> Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using
>   only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Using rails with the version 3.2.11 fixed the bundle.

Rails 3.2.11 fixes a huge security threat anyway, so update !

Comment: I updated the version to 3.2.11. here are the new Gemfile and Gemfile.lock: http://pastebin.com/MLqWnbjh  http://pastebin.com/8KHAr5Lb

I still get the same error, though: "Could not find bourbon-3.0.1 in any of the sources" but bundle show tells that it's installed

Comment: if you remove your Gemfile.lock, what happens ?